# Pyinstaller Error Bundling Egg Files FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller, cx-freeze, egg

I am attempting to convert my python file (.py) into a Windows executable (.exe). To do this, I am using Pyinstaller. My python includes the module PyBluez for Bluetooth capabilities. When I run the command `pyinstaller <path> -F` from the directory of the py file, it gives an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c:\users\X\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pybluez-0.22-py3.7-win32.egg\bluetooth\widcomm.py'

After quite a bit of research, I am unable to figure out what is wrong with my program. Do I need to specifically specify where to find the egg file? If so, How would I do that? Thank you! Also, I tried to use cx_Freeze and it also gave an error about the bluetooth module:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts__startup__.py", line 14, in run
>       module.run()
>     File "C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26, in run
>       exec(code, m.**dict**)
>     File "BuzzerBeater.py", line 3, in 
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bluetooth'

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and managed to solve it by unzipping the .egg file to a folder with the same name (including .egg in the folder name), in my case `C:\Users\X\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\PyBluez-0.22-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\`.